# Closing your Apple Activity rings when watch is being repaired (and unpaired from iPhone)

Tags: apple-watch

Is there any way to be able to have Activity data tracked on the Activity app when you have had to unpair your Apple Watch from your iPhone so it can be repaired?
Using a third-party app to create a workout works when your Apple Watch is paired with your iPhone but not when it has been unpaired.
Is there really no wan to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add workouts and other health data via the Health App directly or using 3rd party Apps. This will also apply the data to the activity app (and rings).

For a workout:

1. Open "Health"
2. Select "Browse" at the bottom
3. Scroll until you find "Workouts"
4. Select "Add Data" in the top right corner.

Comment: This has worked for me before, but now my Apple Watch is unpaired from my iPhone this method doesn't work and that's disy I had to ask this question.